# Image has invalid character? Trouble with graphicx

Tags: graphics, errors

I'm sort of stumped on this one.  I'm trying to include some graphics that I created with Stata in a document.  I'm using pdfLaTeX and `graphicx`. When I try to compile, I get the error message:

```
ERROR: Text line contains an invalid character.

--- TeX said ---
l.1 ^^@
           ^^PJFIF^^@^^A^^A^^A^^A,^^A,^^@^^@^^@C^^@^^A^^A^^A^^A^^A^^A^^A^^..."
```

My file is very simple:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}

\input{jpeg/math.eps.jpeg}
\end{document}
```

I've tried using EPS, JPEG and PDF with the `pdftex` option for `graphicx`.

Any ideas?

Comment: Use `\includegraphics{...}`, not `\input{..}`. And also remove the dot between math and eps in the file name.

Comment: I knew I was doing something stupid.  Thank you.  The dot I think is ok because that's the file name.

Comment: nope, you were right - it doesn't like the .eps.jpeg file name.

Comment: Why are you calling `graphicx` twice? Also, with an up-to-date system, you usually don't need to include a `pdftex` option or the like; I think there might actually be reasons not to do it.

Comment: It is useful to read the package documentation (or at least open it). You can find the documentation file at the web address **ctan.org/pkg/<package_name>** so for `graphicx` it is http://ctan.org/pkg/graphicx

Comment: I think the two graphicx calls are just a typo from copying from my editor to here.  As far as pdftex, me reasons are pragmatic: it didn't work for me when I included some graphics types without that option.

Answer (score 2):

As Ulrike Fisher points out in comments: Use `\includegraphics{...}`, not `\input{..}`. And also remove the dot between math and eps in the file name.